# $$ in jQuery, what's this used for?

Tags: jquery

if someone just write:

```
    $("#downloadTabs>div").each(function(el) {
        el.setStyle("display", "none");
        el.removeClass('active');
    });
```

I would know what is this used for.
But the actually code I read is

```
    $$("#downloadTabs>div").each(function(el) {
        el.setStyle("display", "none");
        el.removeClass('active');
    });
```

There is one more $, and what's this used for ?

Comment: looks like mootools to me (the each part)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The second example is not jQuery, it's MooTools. The $$ can take a CSS selector to return a set of elements just like the $ function in jQuery:
http://mootools.net/docs/core/Element/Element#dollars

prototype.js also has a very similar $$ function that's a shortcut to getElementsBySelector:
http://www.prototypejs.org/api/utility/dollar-dollar

Comment: does prototype/mootools have the `$$.each()` ?

Comment: Ah yeah it's MooTools. The difference being removeClass is called removeClassName in prototype.

Answer (score 2):

It's probably prototype http://www.prototypejs.org/api/utility/dollar-dollar, as mentioned by James.

Yet jquery could have $$, as stated in this article:

http://onehackoranother.com/projects/jquery/jquery-grab-bag/dom-builder.html

Comment: jQuery doesn't have setStyle() though, that would be css().

Answer (score 2):

It might well be that to avoid conflicts with some other library, someone working on your codebase has added a line like this:

```
var $$ = $.noConflict();
```

`$$` is not mentioned in the jQuery source code as far as I can see...